# Read-only connection to SQL Server with PDO DBLIB

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, freetds

Is it possible to create a read-only connection using [PDO dblib](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php), or set an attribute with a similar effect?

```php
$connection = new PDO("dblib:host={$info['host']};dbname={$info['database']}", $info['username'], $info['password']);
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $connection;
```

If not, is there some other PDO driver that would be able to do this that can connect to FreeTDS?

Comment: In your database create a user account with select privileges only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution here is to create account on the db server with readonly permissions, and connect using that.